# Adding to a git submodule locally

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I have a git repository with all my commonly used wordpress plugins.
I also have a wordpress environment with themes and plugins that are in git.

What I want to do is have the common plugins as a submodule in my wordpress environments, however some sites may need extra plugins.  Problem is as far as I can tell wordpress requires all plugins need to be in the 1 plugins folder (so can't have subfolders).

Can I add to a submodule and have it committed to the environment repository without committing to a submodule.

What about when I clone this environment repo, can I get all the plugins, not just the ones in the commonly used plugins repo?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do any modification to those submodules, you could set up a [post-checkout hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), which will sync your submodules with the wordpress plugin directory.
A rsync would only copy the delta (what has changed).